# PHP: Using html_entities correctly. Want all/any characters to be returned in error message

Tags: php, special-characters, html-entities

I'm having trouble returning certain characters in my error message. The setup is as follows:

Whatever the user enters into the textfield (if incorrect), should be returned in the error message. Whether it's a letter, a comma, an ampersand...anything. It seems html_entities or special_chars would be appropriate here.

The following block of code is where I think this idea should be set up. 
The following characters return a blank error message with just the string (is not a valid 4-letter ICAO airport code) attached:

+
"
'
&

This is the code in question. The commented out $error_str is what I'm trying to get working.

```
 else
 {
   //VERIFY ICAO IS IN AIRPORTS.DB
   $airport_query = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS airport_count, LAT, LONG, IATA, Name FROM airports WHERE ICAO = '$icao'";
   $airport_result = $airports_db->queryDB($airport_query);
   foreach($airport_result as $airport_row) {}
     if($airport_row["airport_count"] == 0)
     {
       $error_str = "$icao is not a valid 4-letter ICAO airport code.";
       /* $error_str =  "html_entities($icao) is not a valid 4-letter ICAO airport code."; */     
     }

     $return_array["ICAO"] = $icao;
     $return_array["IATA"] = $airport_row["IATA"];
     $return_array["airport_name"] = $airport_row["Name"];
 }

 $return_array["error"] = $error_str;

 echo json_encode($return_array);
```

Also notice the `echo json_encode` at the bottom. I'm not sure if I should be doing the html_entities on the $error_str or the $return_array.

Any input is appreciated.

Comment: Is this in a function?

Comment: Then you should not echo the array, rather `return $return_array` and as for the answer  check popthestack's answer..you have a syntax error

Comment: Don't think it's a syntax error, as popthestack said it's being filtered out somewhere else.

Comment: I meant syntax error for `htmlentities()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main issues here. The first is that the PHP function is `htmlentities` without an underscore in the name, and the second is that the function call can't be in a string.

This will work:

```
$error_str = htmlentities($icao) . ' is not a valid 4-letter ICAO airport code.';
```

`htmlentities` accepts a string, so running it on `$return_array` will not work. You could do `htmlentities($error_str)` before putting it in the `$return_array`.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: thank you for the reply. See this is the weird thing: doing what you suggested: say I enter XYZ& into the textfield. This will just return "XYZ is not a valid 4-letter ICAO airport code." Why is this?

Comment: Does it return "XYZ&" even when you don't use `htmlentities`? It might be getting filtered out somewhere else.

Comment: Yes even without using htmlentities it will return "XYZ is not a valid 4-letter ICAO airport code."

Comment: Okay, so it's definitely not a problem with htmlentities then. It's filtering out the `&` before it ever gets to your query. Also, your query is vulnerable to SQL injection unless whatever is doing the filtering earlier is also escaping the string. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sql_injection

Comment: Hm, I see. The thing I don't get is why it's taking care of MOST of the characters but not all. Having a peek through all the files isn't bringing up much (in regards to filtering), but I'll keep you posted. Thanks for the input so far.